# Async callback blocks NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have a server-client based NODE.JS application.

**server.js**

```
...
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    if(message.code == 103)
    {
        process_some_data()
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("UNKNOWN MESSAGE");
    }
});
...
```

**client.js**

```
.. sending responses back to server.js
```

the `process_some_data()` function takes about 4 seconds to complete, and when i have just one client it is not a problem, but if i have 10, they all choke and wait till the the last finishes.

I found out that the entire `socket` event waits till he finishes the current job, for example if i comment `process_some_data()`, it will not be frozen

I have tried 2 tweaks but the didn't worked :

```
...
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    if(message.code == 103)
    {
        setTimeout(function() {
            process_some_data();

            console.log("FINISH");
        }, 1)
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("UNKNOWN MESSAGE");
    }
});
...
```

And even used http://caolan.github.io/async/ ,but no use :

```
...
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    if(message.code == 103)
    {
        // Array to hold async tasks
        var asyncTasks = [];

        async.series([
            setTimeout(function() {

                process_some_data();

                console.log("FINISH");
            }, 1)
        ], function (err, results) {
            console.log(results);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("UNKNOWN MESSAGE");
    }
});
...
```

How to make this ASYNC? Really need this.

Thank you.

Comment: node run on single thread. so all your solutions will not work.

Comment: you can try run the function in another process, it will not block... send a message when it finish and thus it will be async.

Comment: It looks like you are doing some blocking IO ops synchronously in  process_some_data function. So why does *process_some_data* function takes so long and why does it block everything??

Comment: @Alon how to make that??
Molda -> it is running some linux commands, takes time, i cannot change that

Comment: @DancoD We'd need to see process_some_data to tell you how to make it asynchronous (it shouldn't block while the linux commands run, it should move on and resolve a Promise or call a callback once the commands have finished).

Answer (score 1):

You need multiple processes to solve this with Javascript, because Javascript engines are *single-threaded*.

#### What?

When it comes to handling I/O events, such as reading a socket, writing to a file or waiting for a signal, Javascript engines give the appearance of doing multiple things at the same time.

**They are actually not**: it's just that, under most conditions, processing these events takes so little computation, and the events themselves occur with so much time in between (a microsecond is an eternity for a CPU), that the engine can just process them one after another with plenty of time to spare.

In human time-scale, it *looks* like the engine is doing a lot of stuff in parallel, but it's just working serially at great speed.

No matter how you schedule your code to run, using `setTimeout` or `Promise`, it will still block other events from being processed during the time it's actively computing. Long-running computations (in the scale of seconds, instead of milliseconds) expose the single-threaded nature of the engine: it cannot actually do multiple things at the same time.

#### Multiple processes

Your computer, however, probably has multiple CPU cores. Unlike the Javascript engine, your hardware is capable of tackling multiple tasks at the same time, at least 1 per core. Even with a single core, your operating system can solve the problem if you run multiple processes.

Since a single Javascript process is single-threaded, you need multiple Javascript processes for this. An easy and time-proven architecture to solve your problem is this:

- One Javascript program, running in one process, reads from the `socket`. Instead of calling `process_some_data()`, however, it puts all incoming messages in a queue.
- This program then sends items from the queue to another Javascript program, running in a different process, that performs the computation using another CPU core. There may be multiple copies of this second process. In a modern computer, it makes sense to have twice as many active processes as you have CPU cores.

A simple approach for Node is to write an HTTP server, using `express`, that runs the computationally-intensive task. The main program can then use HTTP to delegate tasks to the workers, while still being able to read from the socket.

[This](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2014/02/28/taking-advantage-of-multi-processor-environments-in-node-js/) is a good article on the topic of multi-processing with Node, using the `cluster` API.

Comment: Based on the question's comments it sounds like `process_some_data` calls some external processes anyway (the 4 seconds isn't due to computation in Javascript), and just needs to be made asynchronous.

Comment: Multiple CPU cores also isn't a requirement (however likely). A computer with one core could handle some node.js I/O while the other process is running (albeit paused), because the OS will handle the scheduling and context switching between processes.

Comment: Thank you for answering, i get the ideea. What you say with a HTTP server is too complicated (i know how to do it, but it to complicated), but this `cluster` api might be what i want, i have to understand and test it first. I Have to say, i am disappointed, i mean `C#` and `JAVA` catch socket responses in another thread if you feel me ... hoped `node` did the same ...

Comment: @DancoD You don't need a separate thread, you just need to make `process_some_data` run the other linux commands asynchronously instead of synchronously. Someone will be able to help you with that if you show some of the code for that function.

Comment: i cannot, i need the result of the output and send back to the client, what if i use https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/tree/master/samples/multithreading? Or better, i could make an array to keep commands instructions there, then from an function like this http://pastebin.com/r2CaN4pD i will process data there? what about this? Good ideea?

Comment: "i cannot, i need the result of the output and send back to the client" That shouldn't be a problem. You should be able to reply to the client asynchronously.

Comment: @DancoD Synchronous/Asynchronous doesn't affect whether you need to send the response to the client or not, it just affects whether the thread can do other stuff while the data is being processed before the response is sent.

Comment: @DancoD It's pretty straightforward to do it async. You could use a multithreading library intead if you *really* want to, but would greatly complicate things and you wouldn't be likely to see any performance improvement over just doing it async. You definitely won't get any new capabilities that you can't do in a single thread (like responding to the client after the data is processed while letting the thread handle other client requests while the data is processing). That pastebin won't help it all.

Comment: So mainly you guys say that i have to run the function in another process somehow, it is the only way, a fork, something, right?

Comment: It's already another process if it's a linux command, it's just a difference of freeing up the thread to do other stuff while that linux command runs. Doing that depends on how the linux commands are called from your JavaScript code.

Comment: EG, if you use `execSync` right now, then replace that with `exec` instead and pass it a callback, from the callback you can send the response to the client.

Comment: @DancoD Btw, if you want to notify me of a comment, make sure to include `@Paulpro` somewhere in it, otherwise, I won't see it unless I come back here to check. The post owner (slezica) will get notified of all comments, but other commenters will only be notified if you use the `@username`

Comment: @Paulpro thank you for the answers, `freeing up the thread to do other stuff` yes, i know where is the problem, it is like `socket.on('message', function(message) {` is waiting for `process_some_data();` to finish ... i don't know how to make it async ...

Comment: @DancoD You would need to show us the body of the function `process_some_data` for us to be able to make it execute the linux commands asynchronously. That can't be done from outside process_some_data, you need to modify process_some_data itself.